# facebook id string length

Tags: ios, facebook

I had a look on the facebook graph api. [facebook api user object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

I can't see what the **maximum length** that id would be. So that I can store it my database to uniquely identify a user on my game without them needing to register or sign up.

Also is an id unique for each facebook user? - Must be.

id is pulled from JSON "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=fromiPhoneApp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A 64-bit integer is sufficient. Or if you prefer to use a character field, 20 characters. Yes, the ID is unique for each user.

Comment: Cool Thanks. Just its says a string on the site, how come they have been so vague on the api?

Comment: Facebook documentation is notoriously bad unfortunately.